# A way to get the current resolution size and DPI from the command line/terminal/adb?

Tags: adb, command-line, screen-resolution

I've got `adb` access to my android phone.

So I know that I can override screen density and screen resolution with the `am` command provided with Android. That's great and dandy, I guess. But is there a way to grab those two numbers from the command line? I know the `pm` utility can do some information gathering, most notably `pm list features` to see if the Android device has wireless, bluetooth, gps, etc. `pm` doesn't seem to do much more information reporting than this, though.

It would be helpful to know what versions of Android that the command is supported for. Ideally I would like something that works on Android 2.2+ (Froyo), but taking something that only works from 4.0.3+ (Ice Cream Sandwich) is fine too. I would also like it if there was a way to figure this out without root access.

I know that it's possible to get the screen resolution and density programmatically, as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the result and precise format of the `dumpsys` command depends on the hardware vendor (of graphics chipset/driver and handset itself) but you should be able to find that info in the `adb shell dumpsys display` output

Comment: So I could call `adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo` to get the appropriate information? It seems to match up, on my nexus 7 `dumpsys` reports the density to be `213` and the resolution to be `800x1280`. It also reports information on rotation and such, neat. I didn't know dumpsys existed, but it seems to report on *a lot* of useful information as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool

Comment: yes. the problem is that different phones could have a  different format of this line

Comment: **adb shell dumpsys display  | grep mRequestedMode**  Then **adb shell dumpsys display  | grep mMode={id=** to get the modeinfo

Answer (score 13):

In Android versions equipped with *wm* tool, you can use the commands:

```
adb shell wm size      # shows the real size and current size
adb shell wm density   # shows the real density and current density
```

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

I've tested successfully on stock Android 5.x and 6.x. Since *wm* tool comes with Android 4.3.x and 4.4.x as well, the solution *may* work on them as well.

Comment: Note: yes, the question restricts to now archaic Android version but the problem seems relevant for just any Android version. I decided to bring information not covered in accepted answer.

Comment: Is this measurement in pixels?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky that I do not know.

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @Tri Material Terminal Emulator. Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yarolegovich.materialterminal&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: @Firelord when using wm density, my phone reports the supported dpi is 420, but when using dumpsys display | grep dpi, it reports that the display dpi supported is 560. So i am confused on which is the correct reading or if wm density isn't actually dpi? So you know what's going on here?

Comment: I am not to sure about these entries from getprop: `~ $ getprop | grep ro.sf
[ro.sf.init.lcd_density]: [560]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [420]` guess i will Google it

Comment: @james28909 In my OnePlus 6 (Android 11), `wm density` reports Physical density and Override density. Override density is what I (the user) has manually configured. Physical density is that the device came with. dumpsys display reports the same info as BaseDisplayInfo and OverrideDisplayInfo. I don't know about `[ro.sf.init.lcd_density]`.

Comment: @Firelord yes sir, i understand what you mean. I were just wondering why `dumpsys display | grep dpi` reports a higher dpi than wm density. If you use termux or a terminal emulator, try that dumpster command and you will see what i mean. I also wonder what the property `[ro.sf.init.lcd_density]:` is, or what it controls. My Googlefu could not find anything informative about this property. Also, thanks for responding :)

Comment: @james28909 I think you should ask this as a separate question. dumpsys in my device does not report density higher than what wm command does. // No problem. No need to call me Sir. :)

Answer (score 6):

If `display` service isn't available in `dumpsys`, you may look for line `ro.sf.lcd_density=` into `/system/build.prop`. To get it from phone:

```
adb pull /system/build.prop
```